# Using SlashCommandAttribute not working with Discord.Net

Tags: c#, .net, discord, discord.net

Slash commands have been added to [Discord.Net](https://discordnet.dev/#new-in-v3) along side the Interaction Framework.

By going through the documentation, I found out that we can use the `SlashCommandAttribute` inside a module that inherits from `InteractionModuleBase`. More info can be found [here](https://discordnet.dev/guides/int_framework/intro.html).

Please note that I've already had this bot running for over a year now, so it's fully working with basic commands, and I am trying to update it to work with slash commands now.

What I have tried is the following steps:

1. Inside my main method, I listened to client ready event:

   ```
   _client.Ready += _client_Ready;
   ```
2. Inside the _client_Ready function, you can find the following code:

   ```
    private async Task _client_Ready()
    {
        _interactionService = new InteractionService(_client);
        await _interactionService.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), _serviceProvider);
        await _interactionService.RegisterCommandsToGuildAsync(_guildId);
    }
   ```
3. I created a module that inherits from InteractionModuleBase as following:

   ```
   public class TestingSlashCommandModule : InteractionModuleBase<SocketInteractionContext>
   {
       [SlashCommand("test-slash", "Echo an input")]
       public async Task Echo(string input)
       {
           await RespondAsync(input);
       }
   }
   ```

When I run the bot and go to my discord server, I can see the slash command registered:

[image: Image showing the slash command]

However, when I try to use it, I get an error on Discord saying that the application did not respond, and the breakpoint inside the `Echo` function isn't being hit at all.

I am not sure if this is how slash commands are intended to be used because there's [another way](https://discordnet.dev/guides/int_basics/application-commands/intro.html) to do it, apparently, but it doesn't look as clean as the modules with the attributes.

Has anyone been able to use slash commands within the modules using the `SlashCommandAttribute`, and how so?

Comment: maybe try asking in the [DNet Discord](https://discord.gg/Rf98zCRS)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to fix that after I found a section in the documentation called [Executing Commands](https://discordnet.dev/guides/int_framework/intro.html#executing-commands)

I had to add an event listener to `InteractionCreated` on `_client` inside the `_client_Ready` event:

```
private async Task _client_Ready()
{
    _interactionService = new InteractionService(_client);
    await _interactionService.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), _serviceProvider);
    await _interactionService.RegisterCommandsToGuildAsync(_guildId);

    _client.InteractionCreated += async interaction =>
    {
        var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var ctx = new SocketInteractionContext(_client, interaction);
        await _interactionService.ExecuteCommandAsync(ctx, scope.ServiceProvider);
    };
}
```

After doing this, the slash commands are being executed within the modules and I can see the result.

Comment: Any reason you are calling `.CreateScope()` on `_serviceProvider` and then using just using `.ServiceProvider`? Seems kinda pointless.

Comment: Instead of `.CreateScope()`,  `AutoServiceScopes = true` can be used from `InteractionServiceConfig`